# Error en Update en capas con Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data

espero se encuentren bien, estoy haciendo un proyecto con Spring Boot Data JPA Usando Oracle, en el paquete modelo tengo las entidades Cliente y Reporte de mi base:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_cliente")
    private Integer idCliente;
    private String nombre;
    private String correo;
// Setters and Getters ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "reporte")
public class Reporte {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id_reporte")
        private Integer idReporte;
        @Column(name = "id_cliente")
        private int idCliente;
        private String fecha;
    // Setters and Getters ...
}
```

En el paquete repository tengo mis interfaces:

```
@Repository
public interface ReporteRepository extends JpaRepository<Reporte, Integer> {
    List<Cliente> findByIdClienteAndCorreoAndFechaBetween(int cliente, String correo, String fecha1, String fecha2);

}
```

En el paquete controller:

```
public void actualizarReporte() throws ParseException {
        Date fecha = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
        DateFormat fechaHoy = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
        Reporte reporte = new Reporte();
        List<Reporte> lista = reporteRepository.findByIdClienteAndCorreoAndFechaBetween(102, "alguien@mail.com", format.parse("20150401" + " 00:00:00"), format.parse("20150501" +" 23:59:59"));
        System.out.println("Registros encontrados " + lista.size());
        if(lista != null) {
            reporte.setCorreo("desconocido@mail.com");
            reporte.setFecha(fechaHoy.format(fecha));
            reporteRepository.save(reporte);
        } 
        //Acá una consulta
        public void consulta() {
            Optional<Reporte> optional = reporteRepository.findById(113);
            if(optional.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println(optional.get());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No se encontró");
            }
        }
}
```

Y en el paquete vista solo mando a llamar a los métodos:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    ReporteController reporte;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        reporte.actualizarReporte();
    }

}
```

El punto es que intento hacer mi Update parecido al de consulta pero me manda este error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.app.MyApplication.main(PolizaBancosApplication.java:32) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.app.model.Reporte; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.app.model.Reporte
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Espero alguien pueda orientarme o apoyarme ya que soy nueva utilizando Spring. adicionalmente: la base de datos no tiene un id autoincrementable, ya que así está estipulado el diseño ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El secreto para encontrar el detalle del error es mirar en la traza **"Caused by:"** .
En tú caso el problema se detalla.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.app.model.Reporte; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.app.model.Reporte
```

Entonces podremos decir que el error es por que no tienes un identificador antes de llamar al método **save**

Adicional te recomiendo separar los metodos de consulta y update.

```
public void actualizarReporte() throws ParseException {
       /* Aun no entiendo por que haces un format a las fechas*/
        Date fecha = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
        DateFormat fechaHoy = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
        //Reporte reporte = new Reporte(); //Comentamos esto ya que lo requerimos en el foreach (El for de abajo)
        // El método findByIdClienteAndCorreoAndFechaBetween devuelve una lista de la entidad Cliente
        List<Cliente> lista = reporteRepository.findByIdClienteAndCorreoAndFechaBetween(102, "alguien@mail.com", format.parse("20150401" + " 00:00:00"), format.parse("20150501" +" 23:59:59"));

        System.out.println("Registros encontrados " + lista.size());

        //if(lista != null) { //comentamos esto ya que lo que necesitamos es iterar la lista de clientes
          for(Cliente clt: lista){
            Reporte reporte = new Reporte(); //Esto es por que si tenemos 10 clientes se guardaran los 10 
            reporte.setCorreo(clt.getCorreo());
            reporte.setFecha(fechaHoy.format(fecha));
            reporteRepository.save(reporte);
          } 
     }
        //Acá una consulta
        public void consulta() {
            Optional<Reporte> optional = reporteRepository.findById(113);
            if(optional.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println(optional.get());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No se encontró");
            }
        }
```

Ahora bien para que el código anterior funcione y no te siga marcando el error, modificaremos la entidad Reporte.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reporte")
public class Reporte {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id_reporte")
        private Integer idReporte;

        @Column(name = "id_cliente")
        private int idCliente;
        private String fecha;
    // Setters and Getters ...
}
```

La sentencia @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY), se basa en una columna de base de datos con incremento automático y permite que la base de datos genere un nuevo valor con cada operación de inserción. Desde el punto de vista de la base de datos, esto es muy eficiente porque las columnas de incremento automático están altamente optimizadas y no requiere ninguna declaración adicional.

Este enfoque tiene un inconveniente importante si usa Hibernate, ya que requiere un valor de clave principal para cada entidad administrada y, por lo tanto, debe realizar la instrucción de inserción de inmediato. Esto evita que utilice diferentes técnicas de optimización  como el procesamiento por lotes JDBC.

Comment: Hola Omar, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de la explicación, veo los errores que tengo, adicionalmente te comento que la fecha le hago un format porque en la base de datos el formato es yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss y java la saca con el nombre del día. En cuanto al identificador autoincrementable, en la base de datos no se define como tal, ya que así está estipulado ¿Habrá alguna otra forma? ¡Saludos!

Comment: @Lorena con esta anotación         @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    en  las entidades de java, te ayuda a generar los id´s, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

tanto un tu base de  datos, como en tu modelo tienes que indicar que el id es autoincrementable
Para hacerlo en tu modelo tienes que hacer esto

````
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cliente")
    public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_cliente")
    private Integer idCliente;
    private String nombre;
    private String correo;   
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "reporte")
    public class Reporte {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id_reporte")
        private Integer idReporte;
        @Column(name = "id_cliente")
        private int idCliente;
        private String fecha;
    // Setters and Getters ...
       }```
````

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, el detalle es que mis tablas no generan un id autoincrementable así está estipulado.